# Отфильтровать инфоблок типа "Список" по VALUE_XML_ID

Tags: битрикс

```
$months = $_GET["months"];

$arrFilter=array("PROPERTY"=>array("ATT_FILTER_MONTHS"=>"$months"));
```

Есть свойсвто типа список инфоблока - `ATT_FILTER_MONTHS`, у каждого значения из списка есть `VALUE_XML_ID`

Как мне передать его в массив `arFilter` ?

Читаю документацию, пробую `"PROPERTY_<PROPERTY_CODE>_VALUE"` , не получается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы делаете свою выборку то как минимум нужно передать `IBLOCK_ID` и `PROPERTY_ATT_FILTER_MONTHS_VALUE` пишется вместе, пример кода :

```
CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");
    $dbResult = CIBlockElement::GetList(
        array(),
        array(
            'IBLOCK_ID' => 1,
            'PROPERTY_ATT_FILTER_MONTHS_VALUE' => 'test_1',
        ),
        false,
        false,
        array('ID', 'PROPERTY_ATT_FILTER_MONTHS')
    );
    while($arResult = $dbResult->Fetch()){
        echo "<pre>".print_r($arResult, true)."</pre>";
    }
```

Если вы передаете `FILTER_NAME` в компонент то по первых у вас должно быть в `$_GET["months"]` или название пункта списка или `XML_ID`
А ваш `$arrFilter` должен быть глобальной переменной.
Убедитесь что в `$_GET["months"]` приходит именно это значение и что ваш `$arrFilter` не затерается ниже по коду.
Если не найдете ошибки тут то советую залезть в ядро bitrix в нужный вам компонент найти выборку элементов и распечатать там фильтр по которому происходит выборка и найти причину по которой она не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Свойство с кодом `TYPE` и в `XML_ID` записан "main":

```
$GLOBALS['nameFilter'] = array(
    '=PROPERTY_TYPE_VALUE' => CIBlockPropertyEnum::GetList(Array(),
    Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>$arParams["IBLOCK_ID"], "XML_ID"=>"main"))->GetNext()["VALUE"]
);
```